# Production account: integrator key not showing

Tags: docusignapi

I've filled in the form that allows promoting our sandbox key to a live prod account. I haven't  received any reply from docusign  and the key didn't appear in the API and Keys section under the prod account.

Anything that should be done to make it work on production?

thank you

Comment: I think it takes 24-48 hours for Docusign to approve your request after you fill the GoLive form? When did you fill the GoLive form?

Comment: i did it yesterday :(

Comment: Please give it another day and email to apihelp@docusign.com if you don't hear back.

Comment: My comments were about an older process. Please refer to the answer I have posted for the new process to Go Live.

Answer (score 0):

Docusign now has an automated process to Go Live. You can start this process through your developer sandbox, most reviews are completed within hours.

Please refer to the detailed documentation [here](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#enable-key).

> - First login to your [developer sandbox](https://account-d.docusign.com) and from the profile menu select **Go To Admin -> API and Keys**.
> - From your list of integrator keys choose the key you would like to promote and select **ACTIONS -> Review Transactions**.
> - Input the date your 20+ API transactions were run in the demo environment and click **REVIEW** to start the automated review process. Reviews may take up to 20 minutes to complete.